# HMaster not starting up

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have configured Hadoop 2.6.0 successfully. Next, I am trying to install Hbase 0.98.9 but am having trouble starting up Hbase.

I get the below error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool

starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-yarn-master-hadoopmaster.out

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
localhost:

starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-yarn-regionserver-hadoopmaster.out


localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer
```

And, this is my hbase-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
         <property>
         <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
         <value>hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/hbase</value>
         </property>
         <property>
         <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
         <value>/home/yarn/hbase/zookeeper</value>
         </property>
         <property>
         <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
         <value>true</value>
         </property>
        </configuration>
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my configuration.

Regards.

Comment: I think your question is better suited for ServerFault. It's an admin/install issue.

Comment: Am not sure about that. Who can help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `hadoop-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/path/to/hbase/jars
```

> **NOTE:** Change `/path/to/hbase/jars` to hbase jars location. If possible add all available hbase jar files to hadoop classpath (to avoid future class problems).

Comment: Try copying all hbase jars to hadoop lib folder and add classpath for that path.